# How do you fix pylint C0103:invalid-name?

Tags: python, visual-studio, pylint

I installed python on Visual Studio Code today and while coding basic program it showed this problem to me.
I tried finding possible solutions but didn't get any,
Here is a attached SS

Problem : **Module name "pyBasics" doesn't conform to snake_case naming style**

[image: SS of the Problem]

Answer (score 3):

Snake case of `pyBasics` is `py_basics` which is the standard of naming for module.